# Why doesn't the modern C++ library support threads with priority?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, concurrency

Many third party C/C++ libraries providing multithreading support threads' priority, corresponding scheduler, etc. Why doesn't the modern C++ standard support this useful feature?

Comment: Because no one specified it.

Comment: Here's the proposal that eventually became the standard thread library: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2497.html. It doesn't mention priority anywhere.

Comment: @R. do you mean standartization comitee doesn't consider this feature thoroughly?

Comment: I wasn't following the standards track at the time, but either no one presented it for consideration, or if someone did the proposal was not in a desirable shape for inclusion in the standard. The open-std site of WG21 http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/ is a good place to look for such answers.

Comment: Probably because thread priority and other attributes are very system-dependent, making it difficult to make it both portable and useful (but I don't follow the standardisation process in detail, so I don't know whether or not that was the rationale). The thread library does provide a back door, `native_handle()`, to access whatever facilities are available in the native threading API.

Comment: Probably because some systems don't even support it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer, I think, is that if the standard included a way to specify priorities, it would also have to specify what would happen as a result. This, unfortunately would lead to one of two possibilities: either you'd force people to completely re-implement threads from the ground up on systems that had different semantics, or else you'd limit the platforms to which code that used `std::thread` could be ported.

Just for example, on some systems, threads of sufficiently high priority (e.g., "real time priority") use round-robin scheduling. Other systems don't--when a thread of sufficiently high priority starts, it will continue to be scheduled until it runs to completion or is interrupted by a thread of even higher priority. Specifying either behavior would lead to problems porting to systems that use the other.

Many (most?) systems also include some mechanism to prevent starving lower priority threads, so they can continue to receive *some* CPU time even while higher priority threads are ready to run. Again, the details vary and a few (especially smaller/simpler) systems simply don't include any such mechanism at all. As above, attempting to specify any one behavior would lead to difficulty in porting to systems that implement different behavior.

It would be easy to include a `set_priority(int)` (or something similar), but specifying what it meant/did portably would be next to impossible.

Answer (score 7):

Such feature is not specified in the standard, which means that as of today, a "thread" as described by the C++ standard has no priority.

- For POSIX systems you can use `pthread_setschedparam`
- For Windows you can use `SetThreadPriority`

It is easy enough to write a simple wrapper class around those calls (and possibly others if you use other platforms) for your program.

(you would do so by retrieving the native thread handle with [`std::thread::native_handle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/native_handle))

---

[Boost.Thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.tutorial.attributes) offer this note about it :

> Thread launched in this way are created with implementation defined
>   thread attributes as stack size, scheduling, priority, ... or any
>   platform specific attributes. It is not evident how to provide a
>   portable interface that allows the user to set the platform specific
>   attributes. Boost.Thread stay in the middle road through the class
>   thread::attributes which allows to set at least in a portable way the
>   stack size as follows [...]